# 12GB triple channel DDR - BIOS reports 6GB installed

Tags: memory, motherboard

DX58SO Board with an Intel i7 940 CPU and 3x4GB Kingston HyperX DDR3 1066 memory.

This issue appeared recently, in the last 60 days, after 3-4 years of usage. I have 12GB of memory installed but the system only reports 6GB. Windows memory diagnostics report no issues, all the configuration in BIOS is set to the factory default (which is what it's always been).

Given that it reports a value of 6GB, I assume that if it's a memory fault, all three memory modules are faulty, otherwise I would see an available value of 4GB or 8GB, and likely get some beeps on boot - right now I get no beeps, no errors any place.

This leads me to think something is wrong with the motherboard, though I'm seeing no unusual behavior other than the expected decrease in performance in Windows (7, 64-bit). What could cause a board to suddenly stop using 50% of the memory? My best guess so far is that it's not treating the DDR as DDR, not using a double data rate, but that doesn't reall make sense.

Any input appreciated.

Comment: Your conclusions are spot on.  Try each module by itself and see if the system boots.

Comment: One by one, they report 2GB each, as oppose to 4GB.

Comment: The fact you have 4 modules all reporting the same size indicates something else is going on. These sizes were measures in BIOS/UEFI or within the operating system? I would run memtestx86 on each module, do several passes, if you get no errors then that indicates hardware failure.  **The only other possability is you actually have 2GB modules.**

Comment: BIOS. They're 4GB, it's printed on them. And again I've had this system since 2009 and it always reported 12GB of RAM. I'll check out the memtest. I'm starting to think it's just something gone funky with the board. Not sure what it could be, but I'm more or less resigned to building a new rig at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Aparrently the DX58so only support 1gb and 2gb memoru modules!

read here: http://www.intel.com/support/motherboards/desktop/dx58so/sb/CS-029865.htm